# Unable to execute multiple commands from Linux terminal [Red-Hat, Centos, Unix, too]?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, redhat

I  want to execute multiple commands from Linux terminal on Linux Red-hat.

```
 echo deltaasm |. oraenv && snrctl status;
```

```
[oracle@DeltaLinOraASM2 datavail]$  echo deltaasm |. oraenv && snrctl status;
ORACLE_SID = [oracle] ? The Oracle base has been set to /u01/app/oracle
bash: snrctl: command not found
```

If execute the same command on Linux ubuntu it works perfectly. I am unable to execute on Linux Red Hat.
. oraenv script sets oracle home and sid of oracle so oracle related commands will work.
But if i execute from terminal it works ok here is the result

```
[oracle@DeltaLinOraASM2 datavail]$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [oracle] ? deltaasm
The Oracle base has been set to /u01/app/oracle
[oracle@DeltaLinOraASM2 datavail]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 23-MAY-2018 03:07:04

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Start Date                23-MAY-2018 02:34:56
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 32 min. 8 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/DeltaLinOraASM2/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DeltaLinOraASM2)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
[oracle@DeltaLinOraASM2 datavail]$
```

Please suggest on the above problem, thank you

The problem is that I can execute on this Linux Ubuntu, with any trouble but I am facing problem to execute on Linux Centos And some of the other flavors of Linux distro.
Tried on Ubuntu, Not working on Red-Hat, Centos, Unix, too.
Thank You for your suggestion.

Comment: Change to use the full path of the command lsnrctl

Comment: check this : echo deltaasm &&  . oraenv && snrctl status;

Comment: JJJ echo deltaasm && . oraenv && snrctl status; this also don't work

Answer (score 1):

You have missed out an 'l' in the command i guess.
The should be somewhat like

```
echo deltaasm |. oraenv && lsnrctl status
```

Comment: echo deltaasm |. oraenv && lsnrctl status This not working  oracle@DeltaLinOraASM2 datavail]$ echo deltaasm |. oraenv && lsnrctl status
ORACLE_SID = [oracle] ? The Oracle base has been set to /u01/app/oracle
bash: lsnrctl: command not found